# SPException: It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am getting the above exception while trying to upload document into my document library. Here is my code:

```
spFile = spWeb.Files.Add(
                    docUrl,
                    uploadStream,
                    true, // overwrite or add a new version
                    uploadMessage.Metadata.CheckInComment ?? "", //check-in comment to use when creating the file in the collection. (can't be NULL)
                    false);
```

The issue does not occur while manually uploading the file from the browser but while adding the file in a Document Library from the code using SPWeb.Files.Add the above mentioned exception occurs. Please note that the Content DB of the web application is not full or is not set to Read Only.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing what you are doing with powershell as outputting the objects there will give you more insight to your problem.

I would do this slightly differently so i could be sure that the file was going exactly where i wanted it to go.

```
var sp = new SPSite("http://localhost"); 
var site = sp.OpenWeb(); 
var folder = site.GetFolder("Documents"); 
var files = folder.Files; 

// Opening a filestream 
var fStream = File.OpenRead("C:MyDocument.docx"); 
var contents = new byte[fStream.Length]; 
fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length); 
fStream.Close(); 

// Adding any metadata needed 
var documentMetadata = new Hashtable {{"Comments", "Hello World"}}; 

// Adding the file to the SPFileCollection 
var currentFile = 
    files.Add("Documents/MyDocument.docx", contents, documentMetadata, true); 

site.Dispose(); 
sp.Dispose();
```

The code isn't written by me but you can find it at the link

Please check out

http://zimmergren.net/technical/how-to-upload-a-filedocument-using-the-sharepoint-object-model

Cheers
Truez

Comment: DLeh i didn't ask a new question, I simply asked something directly about the issue as well as providing an answer. I don't believe your comment helps. Junaith taken your comments on board and updated the answer.